# Equivalent of Linux /boot directory in an Mac OS?

Tags: linux, macos

In linux /boot, we have the Linux kernel and boot loader files. I wonder whether there is an equivalent of Linux /boot directory in an Mac OS?

Comment: OS X uses `boot.efi` in `/System/Library/CoreServices`. See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KernelProgramming/booting/booting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000905-SW2-BAJJBJEG

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not as a single location; the analogous files are in a number of different filesystem locations:

- The boot loader is /System/Library/CoreServices/boot.efi on Intel Macs. If you have one of the old PowerPC Macs (and an old enough version of OS X), that'd use /System/Library/CoreServices/BootX.
- The kernel is /System/Library/Kernels/kernel in Yosemite (version 10.10), but was just /mach_kernel in older versions.
- Apple-supplied loadable kernel modules (known as kernel extensions or kexts) are found in /System/Library/Extensions/, and third-party extensions in /Library/Extensions/.